# viewing a structure in MPLAB watch window

Tags: embedded, microchip

I want to view a structure in the MPLAB watch window, but when I select it from the "Add symbol" drop down menu I get, "Unsupported Structure".  I was hoping to look for an answer on microchip's forums, but the site seems to be down, so I thought I would test this community out.
  Why is the structure "unsupported"?  How can I get it supported?  Here is the structure I'm trying to see.  Its from mchip's TCP/IP stack.

```
struct BSDSocket
{
    int            SocketType; // Socket type
    BSD_SCK_STATE  bsdState; //Socket state
    WORD           localPort; //local port
    WORD           remotePort; //remote port
    DWORD          remoteIP; //remote IP
    int            backlog; // maximum number or client connection
    BOOL           isServer; // server/client check
    TCP_SOCKET     SocketID; // Socket ID
} ; // Berkeley Socket structure
```

thanks in advance for your help.
Brent

Answer (score 0):

I don't know off the top of my head, but I could suggest a method to get a better idea of what MPLAB is doing.

For testing, try adding a simple structure to your code, with just a single char in it. See if MPLAB can show it. If that works, try adding an int, then a WORD, then DWORD, etc, and see if MPLAB can show it each time.

That should at least let you narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know off the top of my head, but my guess is that the `BSD_SCK_STATE` is an enum, and it's choking on that.